# Using Axiom of Replacement to construct the set of sets that are indexed by a set

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory

I'm now reading the proof of Mitchell's embedding theorem proved in the book of Swan 'Algebraic K-Theory'.

Now I'm trying to understand the sentence

> '*It is well known that for a small abelian category $A$, the functor category from $A$ to the category $Ab$ of abelian groups is well powered, right complete, and has injective envelopes.'*

To understand the well-poweredness, I tried to understand that for a functor $F$, $\{ F(X) \}_{X \in \mathrm{obj}(A)}$ is a set.

I guess the relevant axiom in the set theory is the 'Axiom of Replacement' and it seems that the axiom is understood to be natural because if a collection of elements of a class is indexed by a set, then the collection is also a set because the cardinality of the collection is bounded by the index set. With this explanation, $\{ F(X) \}_{X \in \mathrm{obj}(A)}$ must be a set.

But in the textbooks of set theory, there is a mention of the definable property (more precisely definable in the formal first order language) in the axiom of replacement.

So my question is

In the category theory, do we implicitly assume that a functor is definable? or if not the argument using the cardinality is formal enough?

(By the way, If you can also briefly explain the sentence of the Swan's book, then that would be also a great help! as I'm not meant to be a specialist in this field.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For category theory, rather than using ZFC as the background theory, one usually works with an axiomatic system that treats classes a little more simply, like NBG.  In NBG, the axiom of replacement has no definability requirement for class functions.

If you want to stick with ZFC, then yes you are implicitly assuming that functors are class functions, and hence are definable from first-order formulas in the language (possibly with set parameters).

I personally like to work with ZFC + an axiom of universes.  In this view, one may take every category to be contained in a universe.  Thus, every functor is actually a set, and hence definable (using that set as a parameter).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please suggest a reference? on NBG or the axiom of universe?

Comment: The wiki articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe are okay.  Perhaps someone else can give you a better source.

Answer (score 8):

In the Axiom of Replacement, the "definition" involved is allowed to use *parameters*, i.e. it is allowed to refer to specific sets.  In this case, the functor $F$ is a set, and so your definition using Replacement is allowed to refer to $F$.

(Note that if $A$ were not small, then it would not be possible for a functor on $A$ to be a set (though in some special cases it may be possible to "encode" such functors with sets).  In that case, working in ZFC, it would not be possible to quantify over such functors at all and formulate a theorem such as the one you refer to.  Instead, you would need to work in a set theory that can refer to "large" objects as described in Pace Nielsen's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/379322).)

Comment: Eric, I think the issue is justifying that $F$ is indeed a set in the first place.  In general, a functor between categories is not a set.  So by what principle can you assert that $F$ is a set when the domain is a small category?  If you use an axiom of replacement to do so, that doesn't let you *a priori* claim that $F$ is definable; for the axiom of replacement requires that you have definability before using it.

Comment: In other words, you can't take $F$ to be a parameter *before* you know it is a set.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to formalise functors from a small category $A$ to a large concrete category $C$ is to **define** it as a function $El(F) \to Ob(A)$, where the preimage of $a\in Ob(A)$ is precisely the underlying set of the value of $F$ at $a$, together with some more data specifying the effect of arrows (plus a functoriality condition). In one sense this is defining away the problem, but in fact such an approach is necessary when dealing with these kind of functors in other settings.

For functors to $\mathbf{Ab}$, you would specify that the fibres of $El(F) \to Ob(A)$ are equipped with an abelian group structure, and that the functoriality data respects that.

In this way, no universes are needed, and the data is, informally, exactly what you think it should be.

Comment: "In one sense this is defining away the problem, but in fact such an approach is necessary when dealing with these kind of functors in other settings."  I'm intrigued, and at a loss for why this would be necessary.  I would have thought that in all settings, the functor category was defined in the same way, regardless of whether the domain category is small or not.

Comment: OK, try this: Take an arbitrary topos $E$ with nno as "the" category of constructive sets. This is just a construction of first order logic, so there is no [I]ZF[C] metatheory, so like ETCS but without classical logic baked in. A small category is then an internal category $C$ in $E$. Ask yourself what a functor $C\to E$ can even be. One definition that makes sense is that of an [internal diagram](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+diagram#in_category_theory) (there is also an option using fibred categories), and this is what I was alluding to.

Comment: David, I think you misunderstood my question.  Let $C$ and $D$ be arbitrary categories.  As I understand it, the functor category $D^C$ always exists (whether or not $C$ and $D$ are small).  I find it strange that it would be necessary to use a different **definition** of this functor category when $C$ is small.

Comment: @Pace Well, if you are in ZFC and both $C$ and $D$ are large (and so are given as classes defined by formulae), what is the class of objects of $D^C$? It would require having a class of functions between a pair of proper classes. Even taking NBG as foundation, so you don't need a formula to define a proper class, there is still no such class. It's not so much smallness, but how foundations handle *large* categories.

Comment: True!  But going further, in ZFC there are no such things as "classes" either.  It is just a convenient shorthand.  The superclass of class functions $D^C$ can similarly be viewed as a convenient shorthand.  It is at a level (superclasses) past that of classes, but is it less "real" than classes? [This is one of many reasons I personally favor using ZFC+Universes.]  This said, I think I now understand what you were saying.  I was confused because Swan seems to assume that $D^C$ always exist as a category, and I thought you were working under that same assumption.

Comment: @David Robert Thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain to me the definition of $El(F)$ ?

Comment: @gualterio In this formalism, a functor $F\colon A \to \mathbf{Ab}$ is given by the following data: a function $p\colon El(F) \to Obj(A)$ and specified abelian group structure on each $F(a) := p^{-1}(a)$; a function $f\colon s^*El(F) \to t^*El(F)$ over $Mor(A)$ respecting the abelian group structures, where $s,t\colon Mor(A) \to Obj(A)$ are the source and target functions, and $s^*,t^*$ denote pullbacks. Additionally, $f$ satisfies a functoriality condition: $m^*f$ is the composite of $pr_1^*f$ and $pr_2^*f$, for $m,pr_1,pr_2 \colon Mor(A)\times_{Obj(A)} Mor(A) \to Mor(A)$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you for the answer! So it seems that you're suggesting to start as a working condition that $El(F)=\cup_{a\in Obj(A)}p^{-1}(a)$ is already a set. Then by the axiom of power set, the rest is easily dealt with. I'm intrigued by the ongoing discussion between you and Nielsen. And it seems that Nielsen have understood your point. Could you please explain to me briefly the point of the past discussion? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @gualterio If you restrict yourself to a formulation of category theory where functors only exist when the domain is small, then you can **define away** (rather than **axiomatize away**) any issues with proper classes.  For instance, you could baldly assert: "A functor from a small category $C$ to an arbitrary category $D$ consists of a (set-sized) function from the objects of $C$ to a small subclass of the objects of $D$ together with...". [I don't know many mathematicians who work in a category theory thus restricted.  They seem to prefer an axiom of universes viewpoint, when pressed.]

Comment: @PaceNielsen Thank you very much for the clarification! I will look for the expositions on the axiom of universe too!